# Output $(rpm -Va) to array with spaces intact

Tags: arrays, bash, while-loop

I'm attempting to put the output from `rpm -Va` into an array so that I can then run multiple checks against the results. I would very much like to be able to have each output line from the rpm command be its own line in the array. So far I haven't had too much luck, so I thought it best to reach out and see what other people think. I've tried some of the below options, but to no avail.

This adds to the array but doesn't keep spaces:

```sh
rpmarr=($(rpm -Va | sed 's_^_"_g' | sed 's_$_"_g'))
```

This adds to the array but as one huge line:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do rpmarr+=("$line"); done < "$(rpm -Va)"
```

This also adds to the array but as one huge line:

```sh
IFS=$'\n'; set -f; rpmarr=$(rpm -Va); set +f; unset IFS; echo ${#rpmarr[@]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bash 4.0:

```
readarray -t rpmarr < <(exec rpm -Va)
```

Else

```
rpmarr=() i=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    rpmarr[i++]=$line  ## Can be rpmarr+=("$line") in which case you won't need i. Only available in Bash 3.1+
done < <(exec rpm -Va)
```

`<(exec rpm -Va)` is a form of process substitution and `exec` saves forking another subshell.

Comment: Looks like my account is too new to be able to upvote, but I would if I could since this worked for me! I was able to print the array with the spaces in tact with a test while loop.

Comment: I'm trying to add both to a script file as provided but neither seem to function properly. I'm getting errors like below. Searching around now to see if I can find something.

test: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token '<'
test: line 3: `         readarray -t rpmarr < <(exec rpm -Va)'

Comment: How do you run your script? Perhaps it's not exactly `bash` that runs it?

Comment: I usually use sh -vx ./script 2> out when testing execution and remove the verbose/debugging/output when running for real, unless needed. This time was with the -vx options. I checked /bin/bash --version and it states "GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release".

Comment: Try to run it as `bash -vx ./script` instead. Bash emulates nearly like POSIX sh when called with just `sh`.

Comment: That did it! Is it best practice to use bash over sh? I wasn't aware that sh acted differently. I assumed one was an alias for the other, but never looked into it like I should have.